# Cannot return array if item not present in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a function that will take an array of `jobs` as a parameter in it. This function will check the existence of each `job` in the database through its `id`.

If a job is not to present in the database, that particular job needs to be pushed into an array called `latestJobs`. I'm calling this function in my `main.js` file. But the code breaks and stops.

Below is my **main.js** code:

```
module.exports.app = async () => {
 try {
    ...
    const jobs = await getJobsForCountries(body);
    const latestJobs = await filterPreDraftedJobs(jobs);
    console.log('latestJobs', latestJobs);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error:- ', e); // Comes to here
  }
};
```

My checker function looks like:

```
module.exports = async (jobs) => {
  let latestJobs = [];
  for (const job of jobs) {
    const params = {
      TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
      Key: {
        id: job.Id
      }
    };
    await dynamoDb.get(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        latestJobs.push(job);
        console.log('Job not found in DB'); 
      }
    }).promise();
  }
  return latestJobs;
};
```

[image]

How can I fix this issue? **I want the `latestJobs` which will not present in the database. Is there a function for dynamodb which can do this for me?**

Comment: Check again `process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE` value.

Comment: @hoangdv Yeah it has a valid value

Comment: @preethiR ??? :D . I don't think so, I think you do not have any table with name is `process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE` on your system. `dynamoDb.get` always return success if item with id value is `job.Id` existed or not. In not found case, you can check `data.Item === null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing callback, promise and await style. I would do it like this

```
module.exports = async (jobs) => {
  let latestJobs = [];
  for (const job of jobs) {
    const params = {
      TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
      Key: {
        id: job.Id
      }
    };
    try {
      const result = await dynamoDb.get(params).promise();
      if (result) {
       return; 
      }
    } catch(err) {
      latestJobs.push(job);
    }
  }
  return latestJobs;
};
```

Also, make sure that table is created and the region and name you are passing is correct.

Comment: I have changed my code as you have suggested. But the control flow never goes inside `if(!result)` block. Instead it is going into catch block.

Comment: I figured it out. I have just moved the `latestJobs.push(job)` inside `.catch` block. And now it is working.

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik glad it worked. by the way what is the error you are getting in catch?

Comment: Why can't you write clean and module function to handle this, the code above looks unhealthy

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik This mean `latestJobs.push(job);` always be call, although item is existed or not ???

Comment: @Sohan Can you suggest an answer for this?

Comment: @hoangdv Ohh yeah... I haven't think it through. Can suggest what should be to run `latestJobs.push(job)` only when job is not present in DB?

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik make sure that you have a table with name is `process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE`

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik ohh, just change value of `process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE` to `not_exist_table`, and I think you get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206406/discussion-between-yashwardhan-pauranik-and-hoangdv).

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with `dynamoDB` but looking at the above conversation code must be something like this. I have tried to improve performance and making sure the code is modular and readable.

```
async function addUpdateJobs(jobs)
{
    let paramsArray = [];
    for (const job of jobs)
    {
        const jobParams = {
        params:{
            TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
            Key: {
                id: job.Id
            }               
        },
         job:job
    };
        paramsArray.push(jobParams );

    }
    return await this.getJobs(paramsArray);
}


function getJobs(paramsArray)
{
    let latestJobs = [];
    paramsArray.each(async (jobParam)=>
    {
        try
        {
            const result = await dynamoDb.get(jobParam.params).promise();
            if (result)
            {
                return;
            }
        } catch (err)
        {
            latestJobs.push(jobParam.job);
        }
    });
    return latestJobs;

}
```

PS: Also I was gonig through error handling in [amazondynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html).

Comment: The above code is modular, but when I split I have to run 2 loops instead of one.

Comment: Look at this way, within a loop every time you are trying to do some expensive operation and other jobs are waiting. Why not iterate over loop of params we need? Initial loop we are iterating will have no performance impact. Code looks clean and neat. More important is, it is human readable.

Comment: There will be no` job` instance in the catch block

Comment: If job is not found you get the error right, and param include the ` id: job.Id` right?

Comment: The variable `job` is not present in the `getJobs()` where it is being pushed. Hence wil throw error.

Comment: updated answer, this now populates JOB as well that can be used later to push the jobs